# Aligning Multiple authors in the same line in IEEEtran

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ieeetran, author

[image: IEEE PDF]

There are two author blocks in the paper, but they are spanning multiple lines. Instead, I would like the two of them to be in the same horizontal level.

Here's the code:

```
\begin{document}
\title{\huge Preparation of Papers in Two-Column Format\\
for icma2015 Proceedings Published by IEEE$^{*}$\footnoterule\thanks{$^{*}$This work is partially
supported by NSF Grant \#2003168 to H. Simpson and CNSF Grant \#9972988 to M. King}}

% author names and affiliations
\author{\authorblockN{Karen Garfield and Mickey Mouse}
\authorblockA{\textit{Department of Nuclear Power Engineering}\\
\textit{University of Northland}\\
\textit{Iqaluit, Nunavut, M2M 6H6, Canada}\\
\textit{\{kgarfield, mmouse\}@unorthland.ca}\\}%
\and
\authorblockN{Monkey King, Bajie Zhu, and Seng Tang}
\authorblockA{\textit{Department of Intelligent Robotics}\\
\textit{University of Huaguoshan}\\
\textit{Huaguoshan, Jileshijie Province, China}\\
\textit{monkey.king@uhuaguoshan.edu.cn}\\}
}
```

Is there any way to reduce the width of these two author blocks and bring them to the same horizontal level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, you just have to use the IEEE defined commands:

```latex
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\title{Some meaningless title which only serves to illustrate my point}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Karen Garfield and Mickey Mouse}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Nuclear Power Engineering\\
    University of Northland\\
    Iqaluit, Nunavut, M2M 6H6, Canada\\
    \{kgarfield, mmouse\}@unorthland.ca}\\%
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Monkey King, Bajie Zhu, and Seng Tang}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Intelligent Robotics\\
    University of Huaguoshan\\
    Huaguoshan, Jileshijie Province, China\\
    monkey.king@uhuaguoshan.edu.cn\\}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Turns out, I just had to use the IEEE defined commands and put \\ at appropriate places. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @r-arvind, sure, my pleasure!